# SequelizeJS: How to know success or failure when executing an INSERT raw query?

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

I use PosgreSQL. Now I have an INSERT raw query. I want to know ask 2 questions:

1. I want to know if it is success or failure when executing it
2. If success, I want to get the new data I inserted

   var querydb = INSERT INTO chat_message VALUES (DEFAULT, '${text}',
   '${created_at}', '${room_id}', '${user_id}');

   sequelize.query(querydb, { type: sequelize.QueryTypes.INSERT})
       .then(insertID => {
       resolve(insertID)
   })
       .catch(err => {
       reject(err)
   })

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First of all you shouldn't be using raw queries** until unless you are not able to do anything with sequelize.js , or else there is no use of using this library.

**Use sequelize.js as much as possible , so that you can use default functionality very easily.**

So this is how you can do the same thing in sequelize.js way :

```
ChatMessage.create({
    text: text,
    room_id: room_id,
    user_id: user_id
    created_at: new Date() // Not required , it will be auto managed by sequlize
}).then(message => {
    console.log(message);
    // you can now access the newly ChatMessage task via the variable message
}).catch(err => {
    // catch error if anything goes wrong
})
```

Comment: Vivek, Because I define it in Django (other Web Server). So I think not need re-define Model in SequelizeJS. Is that right?

Comment: @KitKit , nope it doesn't matter , you need to define it on SequelizeJS , as its ORM.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will do your instruction!